# Adding objects to a list - error in code

Tags: java

I have to write a program as homework, and I got stuck with a problem, for which I can't encounter the solution. Maybe you guys can help me. 
I have on class:

```
public class Listas {
    //atributos
    private Medico[] medicos;
    private Enfermera[] enfermeras;

    //Constructor
    public Listas(){
        medicos = new Medico[5];
        enfermeras = new Enfermera[5];
    }

    //Sets y gets
    //Medicos
    public void setMedicos(Medico[] medicos){
        this.medicos = medicos;
    }
    public Medico[] getMedicos(){
        return medicos;
    }
    //Enfermeras
    public void setEnfermeras(Enfermera[] enfermeras){
        this.enfermeras = enfermeras;
    }
    public Enfermera[] getEnfermeras(){
        return enfermeras;
    }

    Medico med1 = new Medico(1, "Juan" , "Pérez", "6799652-3", "1234567870101", 89098, 15000, true);
    Medico med2 = new Medico(2, "Luis", "Gutiérrez", "8964547-3", "9876543260101", 98554, 12000, false);
    Medico med3 = new Medico(3, "Eduardo", "González", "8786456-6", "5642871750101", 5653, 17000, true);
    Medico med4 = new Medico(4, "Guadalupe", "Torres", "5684873-1", "4562973920101", 10098, 17000, true);
    Medico med5 = new Medico(5, "María", "Castillo", "8765485-7", "569395290101", 67965, 13000, false);

    medicos[1] = med1;
    medicos[2] = med2;
    medicos[3] = med3;
    medicos[4] = med4;
    medicos[5] = med5;  
}
```

}

The program tells me that there is something wrong at the end of the line where I trie to define the variable med5. 
All I want to do is to add med1 to 5 to the array medicos[]. The constructor of med1 - 5 are in another class, called Medico.

Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Step 1: Learn to indent/format code readably.

Comment: What's the specific error?

Comment: when you define an array of size 5, you need to use indexes from 0 to 4. but not 5...

Comment: See these guidelines for homework questions: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot assign values of the `medicos` field like that, outside of methods.

Another mistake you made is with the indexing. You assigned `medicos[5]`, but since you initialized it as `new Medico[5]`, the last available index is 4. You probably want to assign the `med*` values to `medicos[0]`, ..., `medicos[4]`.

Perhaps you wanted to do this:

```
public Listas(){
    medicos = new Medico[5];
    enfermeras = new Enfermera[5];

    Medico med1 = new Medico(1, "Juan" , "Pérez", "6799652-3", "1234567870101", 89098, 15000, true);
    Medico med2 = new Medico(2, "Luis", "Gutiérrez", "8964547-3", "9876543260101", 98554, 12000, false);
    Medico med3 = new Medico(3, "Eduardo", "González", "8786456-6", "5642871750101", 5653, 17000, true);
    Medico med4 = new Medico(4, "Guadalupe", "Torres", "5684873-1", "4562973920101", 10098, 17000, true);
    Medico med5 = new Medico(5, "María", "Castillo", "8765485-7", "569395290101", 67965, 13000, false);

    medicos[0] = med1;
    medicos[1] = med2;
    medicos[2] = med3;
    medicos[3] = med4;
    medicos[4] = med5;
}
```

A final note about your original code outside of methods:

```
public class Listas {

    public Listas() {
        medicos = new Medico[5];
        // ...
    }

    // *1
    Medico med1 = new Medico(1, "Juan" , "Pérez", "6799652-3", "1234567870101", 89098, 15000, true);

    // *2
    medicos[1] = med1;
```

- *1 compiles: it's the declaration of a member variable `med1`
- *2 doesn't compile, it's invalid syntax.

You can have field declarations outside of methods, but the case of *2, well, that's just plain invalid grammar.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that I can't assign values of the medicos field outside of a method. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

when you define an array of size 5, you need to use indexes from 0 to 4. but not 5...

also you need to wrap the initialization in a method, or simply do it in the constructor.

```
public Listas(){
    medicos = new Medico[5];
    enfermeras = new Enfermera[5];

    Medico med1 = new Medico(1, "Juan" , "Pérez", "6799652-3", "1234567870101", 89098, 15000, true);
    Medico med2 = new Medico(2, "Luis", "Gutiérrez", "8964547-3", "9876543260101", 98554, 12000, false);
    Medico med3 = new Medico(3, "Eduardo", "González", "8786456-6", "5642871750101", 5653, 17000, true);
    Medico med4 = new Medico(4, "Guadalupe", "Torres", "5684873-1", "4562973920101", 10098, 17000, true);
    Medico med5 = new Medico(5, "María", "Castillo", "8765485-7", "569395290101", 67965, 13000, false);

    medicos[0] = med1;
    medicos[1] = med2;
    medicos[2] = med3;
    medicos[3] = med4;
    medicos[4] = med5;
}
```